# Rails - Saving Nested Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, nested

I was able to create nested arrays in my view to post to my 'create' action. But I'm not sure how to save the nested array.

Here's the basic create action where it gets all individual params bunched in mass-assigned params:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:mass_assigned])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html
    else
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

But this returns a nil object error. It's likely due to my form using the check_box_tag rather than using the check_box with comes with nifty magic and causes the :mass_assigned to be nil. I'm fairly new to rails and would appreciate any leads to get this working. Please explain how to format my method to collect the individual params then save it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your problem is just saving an object or you want to serialize it - and your problem is that your "nested array" you want to inject into db is being flattened before save or something.

If it's the first then please make sure you have params[:mass_assigned] available. You could always add a line, on the top of your controller method:

```
throw params
```

...and submit your form to see what you have available and examine the structure.
Would be nice to see the code of the form you're submitting with a backtrace of an application error taken from the logs

If it is the second case, then let me know and I'll get back to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a full day myself. In case you are still looking for an answer, and if I understand your question correctly, try the following example:

a) Use scaffolding for Person name:string address:text, to set up model,views et al.

b)

```
In app/models/person.rb:
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :address, :name
    serialize :address
end
```

The scaffolding view has the same _form partial for new and edit views.  You can get the new and show actions to complete successfully by putting the following code in the form:

```
<%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
 ...
      <%= f.fields_for :address do |address_fields| %>
        Street  : <%= address_fields.text_field :street %>
        Zip code: <%= address_fields.text_field :zip_code %>
      <% end %>
...
<% end %>
```

However, the edit view will not populate the textfields with the values from the model with the above code.  To solve that you need to extract the value from the @person.address hash and assign it to the text explicitly.  If you are using scaffold views, then the form is typically rendered using a _form partial. This complicates things because adding the code to extract the value of address components blows for new object. You can get past that by initializing the address hash during Person.new or checking for nil as done below:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :address do |address_fields| %>
    Street  : <%= address_fields.text_field :street,:value => @person.address.nil? ? "":@person.address["street"] %>
    Zip code: <%= address_fields.text_field :zip_code,:value => @person.address.nil? ? "":@person.address["zip_code"] %>
  <% end %>
```

Hope that helps.